# Extract zip and contents to a folder in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to unzip a file in php but i'm having directory problems, if i have a zip folder called test.zip
It unzips this way

```
test.zip
  -> test
    -> content 1
    -> content 2
    -> content 3/
       -> content inside content 3
```

However i want to unzip this way

```
test.zip
  -> content 1
  -> content 2
  -> content 3/
     -> content inside content 3
```

I've used the ZipArchive library to no avail

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($directoryName . '/test.zip') === TRUE) {
$zip->extractTo($directoryName);
$zip->close();
```

Comment: @magnus Yeah, it extracts well but i don't want it extracted to a subdirectory

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Ahh, my bad

Comment: @LDUBBS Would you mind deleting the folder later after extraction?

Comment: @Vivek you mean the zip file itself, i don't mind that at all.

Comment: @LDUBBS I mean extract all, later move to `test` and copy all its files outside of it and then later delete `test`

Comment: @Vivek i don't mind so far the files are copied and moved elsewhere, the zip file may also contain subfolders though

Comment: @LDUBBS that's fine. All you want to do is remove the parent one. So lookup online on how to traverse subdirectories recursively. By the way, may I ask why zip that way in the first place?

Comment: @Vivek if i do this i'll get the list of files and folders respectively then i can move into a folder of my choice and delete parent folder. I think i have it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

If you are extracting the ZIP file in current folder, after the extractions move the folder contents and delete the folder:

```
shell_exec("mv ./test/* ./ && rm -R test");
```

Should not be but if the folder is in root

```
shell_exec("mv /test/* / && rm -R /test");
```

Try this:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($directoryName . '/test.zip') === TRUE) {
$zip->extractTo($directoryName);
$zip->close();

shell_exec("mv $directoryName/test/* $directoryName/ && rm -R $directoryName/test");
```

Comment: what if test.zip is dynamic, say the zip file is uploaded and could have any name?

Comment: you mean this Subfolder may have any name? If the Subfolder changes its name from `test` to something else, then you can use `ls` to get its name dynamically and used that.

Comment: I mean test.zip could be xx.zip, how will shell_exec() catch that?

Comment: It's an another question, anyway: How are you getting this file? You need to determine the name of ZIP file when you are getting it. If a user is uploading it then check PHP superglobal variables such as `var_dump($_SERVER);` or `var_dump($_FILES);` or `var_dump($_POST);` etc.. There you should find the name of ZIP file.

Comment: There's a problem with this solution. It heavily relies on what OS you run this on so it isn't particular portable. If someone would try using this on Windows (like a developer with WAMP or similar), this won't work. Since there's nothing here that can't be done directly in PHP, it's better to do it directly in PHP.